# Are item loader fields in scrapy reusable?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Item loader has 2 fields A and B. I want B to pick up from where A left.

Currently xpaths and input processors have to be separately passed for both.

crawler.py

```py
loader.add_xpath('version',"./tr[1]/td[3]/a")
loader.add_xpath('date',"./tr[1]/td[3]/a")
```

items.py

```py
version=scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(get_version,remove_vernacular)
    )
date=scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(get_version,remove_vernacular,get_date)
    )
```

Here version is A and date is B. I want something like below.

```py
date=some_function(version)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of [`ItemLoader`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.ItemLoader) that, when given a value for `version`, automatically adds a value based on it to `date`.

---